# Using CSS dimensions in react-native

Tags: react-native

In normal css, dimensions like **px, %, rem** etc. works perfectly. But in react native, it throws an error.

Are there any possible ways to use these dimensions directly in react-native ?

Comment: Can you show how you are writing them?

Comment: @Autticat In a same way as we write in normal css
  offerCards:{
    width: 130,
    borderRadius: 50%,
}

But it throws unexpected token error when adding '%' to borderRadius, otherwise works fine.

Comment: Just pass the 50% as a string, not as a number. borderRadius : "50%"

Answer (score 2):

REMs are a way of setting font-sizes based on the font-size of the root HTML element.
react native is purely works on pixels. Different mobile screens have different pixel ratio .

[pixelRatio documentation in react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio)

if you want text normalization in react native
use my custom function in my open [source project](https://github.com/bytefuge/Anime-jisho/blob/master/src/widget/Text/normalize.js).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want the width to be 50% of the `View` so you can do `<View style={{width:'50%'}} />` .

Hope its clear. Feel free for doubts.